# cakephp 2.4: pass value instead of id in url?

Tags: cakephp-2.4

I m new to cakephp, want to know how can i change url like this

C:/xyz.com/countries/view/5  to  C:/xyz.com/countries/ABC

where 5 is id of ABC country

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Router::connect('/countries/:country_id', array('controller' => 'countries', 'action' => 'view'), array('pass' => array('country_id')));
```

In the controller:

```
public function view() {
   $countryId =  $this->request->params['country_id'];
}
```

Comment: did the same, used public function view($id=null){$countryId=$this->request->params['id']; ... ...} and added Router::connect('/countries/:id', array('controller' => 'countries', 'action' => 'view'), array('pass' => array('id'))); in routes.php file but giving me error Notice (8): Undefined index: id in this line $countryId =  $this->request->params['id']; and not making any change in url..

Comment: It doesn't work for me, giving this Notice (8): Undefined index: id in this line $countryId = $this->request->params['id']; if i use $countryId = $this->request->params['pass'][0]; then not getting that notice but need 'id'

Comment: `debug($this->request->params);` to see what you are getting. And then use that variable

Comment: getting array(
 'plugin' => null,
 'controller' => 'countries',
 'action' => 'view',
 'named' => array(),
 'pass' => array((int) 0 => '1'))

Comment: if you use it exactly as in the answer, it will send `$country_id` with the correct value